# Cassandra (CQL) select statement with 'where' is not working

Tags: php, cassandra, cql, phpcassa

I am using Cassandra last few days. I am using PHPCassa library for that.

When I am trying to use the following code, Its not working correctly.

```
 require_once('phpcassa/connection.php');
 require_once "phpcassa/columnfamily.php";

 // Create new ConnectionPool like you normally would
 $pool = new ConnectionPool("newtest");

 // Retrieve a raw connection from the ConnectionPool
 $raw = $pool->get();

 $rows = $raw->client->execute_cql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE KEY='phpqa'", cassandra_Compression::NONE);

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($rows);
 echo "<pre>";

// Return the connection to the pool so it may be used by other callers. Otherwise,
// the connection will be unavailable for use.
$pool->return_connection($raw);
unset($raw);
```

Its returning nothing, I have also tried following queries

```
$rows = $raw->client->execute_cql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE age='32'", cassandra_Compression::NONE);
$rows = $raw->client->execute_cql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE name='jack'", cassandra_Compression::NONE);
```

But When I tried

```
 $rows = $raw->client->execute_cql_query("SELECT * FROM User", cassandra_Compression::NONE);
```

Its given the correct answer, displayed all the rows. Please advise me, how to use 'WHERE' properly.

Keyspace Details

```
Strategy Class:     org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy
Strategy Options:   None
Replication Factor: 1

Ring

   Start Token: 6064078270600954295
   End Token: 6064078270600954295
   Endpoints: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: What's the output of 'DESCRIBE USER KEYSPACE'?

Comment: Are 'age' and 'name' indexed?

Comment: In this query "SELECT * FROM User WHERE KEY='phpqa'", phpqa is the key name for that row data.

Comment: Do we need to index the KEY for that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cassandra you cant just query a 'table' as you would normally. You need to set up secondary indexes for every column you might want to query.

Say we have a table:

```
 key      | User |   Age 
----------+----------------
 phpqa    | Jack |   20
```

You can query directly on the key:

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE key='phpqa';
```

But to carry out other WHERE queries you'd need a secondary index on the columns you want to have available in the WHERE clause.

What can you do to make your querying flexible in the way that you desire:

1. [Secondary indexes](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/issues/44) as described above.
2. Use composite columns as your key. Its a good idea if you only have 2-3 columns you want to query, but have a read through [this article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1) detailing how and when to use composite keys, and here is a link in how to implement it in [phpcassa](http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/cassandra-phpcassa-composite-types.html).

Comment: Do we need to index the KEY for that ?

Comment: @phpqa.in Say you want to have the Age column in the WHERE clause (as in `SELECT * FROM user WHERE age=12` You need to index the AGE column. If you want AGE and NAME you need to index both columns. The key column is always indexed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, After adding the secondory index for age, now its working, But i am not able to do <, <= like operators. Also Query with KEY is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Add 'name' and 'age' as secondary indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX name_key on User( name );  
CREATE INDEX age_key on User( age );
```

Then you should be able to use your `select` statement(s).

Read more [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/dml/using_cql).

Comment: Thanks. Do we need to add separate index for KEY ?

Comment: so this should smoothly right?  SELECT * FROM User WHERE key='phpqa'; But fortunetelling its not.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing the data.

Answer (score -3):

you are using a reserved word as a column name:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

```
$raw->client->execute_cql_query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE KEY='phpqa'", 
cassandra_Compression::NONE)
```

Comment: Isn't the post about cassandra? Not MySQL.